# Как восстановить объект при входе в приложение?

Tags: android

Что использовать, чтобы при выходе из приложения сохранить объект, а уже на входе восстановить его?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предполагается обеспечить сохранение/восстановление между выходом и входом (то есть после `finish()`) - надо использовать сохранение в `SharedPreferences`.

Если объект предполагаемый к сохранению сложный, то надо сериализовать во что-то типа Json. Как это сделать через Google Gson - @McDaggen дал [прекрасную ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)

Как альтернативу можно предложить сериализацию через `writeObject` (так сказать родной способ для Java):

```
MyObject myObject; //объект который нужно сериализовать
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //байтовый массив куда пишем
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(myObject); //пишем объект
oos.close();
//кодируем байтовый массив в base64
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
//готовим префы
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
//пишем в префы с ключом "myObject"
editor.putString("myObject", base64);
editor.commit();
```

Обратную десериализацию уже сами - без меня.

**Update**

Совсем забыл: тип/класс `myObject` должен реализовывать интерфейс `Serializable`